# post-commit email to office365 from visualsvn

Tags: email, svn, office365, visualsvn-server

I am trying to send a post-commit email to an exchange distribution list hosted on [office365.com](http://office365.com). They require TLS. I have tried to follow the instructions at: http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00018/ but cannot get it working. Here is the config I used, with username and passwords modified:

> `"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\VisualSVNServerHooks.exe" ^
>       commit-notification "%1" -r %2 ^
>       --from fromemail@example.com ^
>       --to commit@example.com ^
>       --smtp-server smtp.office365.com ^
>           --smtp-ssl ^
>           --smtp-port 587 ^
>           --smtp-user fromemail@example.com ^
>           --smtp-password APassword`

When commit, the changes are committed, but I get this error message:

Warning: post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:
VisualSVNServerHooks: E020014: The transport failed to connect to the server.

I am able to telnet to smtp.office365.com 587 from the system running svn. Post-commit emails work to a different, non-SSL account.

Has anyone else been able to get this to work?

Comment: Brian thanks for the formatting fix. How did you do that?

Comment: Specify the error you get, please.

Comment: I have added the error message I get. Not giving the error message was an oversight, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: No I did not find a solution. This is a bit old now, but the last time I worked on this visualsvn did not actually supported ssl.

Answer (score 1):

Switching to port `465` for SSL connection worked for me, and I was able to `telnet` to `587` from my svn server

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and send a mail to the VisualSVN-Support-Team. This is the answer:

> I regret to say it, but there is a chance that there might be issues with TLS (STARTTLS). This is a known issue. The `VisualSVNServerHooks.exe` doesn't support commit-notification through SMTP with STARTTLS. At the moment, I can suggest using port 465 with SSL-enabled SMTP server if possible. Alternatively, switch to port 25 without SSL/TLS.

This issue is already escalated to our developers. We will consider implementing this option in future VisualSVN Server releases.

I recived this answer at March 22 ' 2018.

Answer (score 0):

Is the environment variable `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%` defined? Are you getting any exit value on your commits? If a post-commit hook fails, you'll get an error message on a commit, but the commit would have worked because the hook is triggered after the commit.

You say you're not able to telnet. Are you simply doing `telnet smtp.office365.com` or are you adding in the port too: `telnet smtp.office365.com 587`. That port number is important. Very rarely does anyone run `telnet` as a service any more. The standerd `telnet` port #23 is usually dead, but the `telnet` command lets you try other ports.

If you can't reach the port, make sure your router isn't blocking Port 587. You can also try my post-commit Watcher. It uses Perl, but you can install [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com) on Windows. VisualSVN uses a standard Apache with mod_svn. The main thing is that it gives you a pretty front end, but the standard hook setup should work fine. At least it'll give you another avenue to try.

Comment: I have edited the post to add the error message. I am able to telnet from the svn system to smtp.office365.com port 587. So it is not network or firewall.

Comment: I found [this](http://www.aspisfun.com/code/mail/transport.html) post. It could be that your SMTP server is setup to reject messages from your SVN server. A good test is to setup another mail account (like Gmail) and use that account's SMTP server. If you can send email, and you can connect to your Exchange SMTP server, it's likely that your Exchange server is setup to reject email from various servers in your company.

Comment: I can send email to another email account from svn, but it is a non-SSL account. I can send email to the destination address from other accounts. If office365.com were blocking my svn server, would I be able to connect via telnet?  My guess is that VisualSVNServerHooks.exe does not send SSL properly. I am going to try sending email some other way, either with your script or a PowerShell script.

Comment: My script sends out plain text emails. Users create a _watch file_ in the Subversion repo saying where they want the notifications and what changes should trigger the notifications.